# DRF nested serializer put very deep field in top level without intermediary layers

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a legacy application that has model relations eight levels deep relative to the top entry point (`A -> B -> C -> D -> E -> F -> G -> H`), and `F -> G -> H` jumps over into Mongo. I know that I could write serializers for each level and reference each, [as in the DRF documentation example here](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#example). Then my output would end up eight levels deep, which is not what I want. What I want is to summarize the single field from model H in the endpoint for A.

I only need read-only access to the data in `H`. What I'm considering doing is implementing a custom `serializers.RelatedField` to `B` and using its `to_representation()` method to do the lookups. Is this the recommended approach?

Comment: Am I right in thinking that you want to include a field in the serializer for A that has data for H (which goes across some form of api?)

Comment: @Sayse - yes, I want to include a field in A for the data in H. They both use django rest, but the mongo part uses django-rest-framework-mongoengine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [SerializerMethodField](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield)

```
my_h = serializers.SerializerMethodField()


def get_my_h(self, obj):
    return obj.b.c.d.e.f.g.h or some_better_logic_here_to_actually_get_h
```

The actual logic above you'll need to tweak to suit your needs (and I wouldn't expect it to perform well due to the level you're trying to reach)... but essentially `obj` is the current instance you're serializing so you can work with it as you wish